# Write time to date time format.

Tags: cassandra, scylla

Is there any option to convert write time into timestamp because scylla giving write time of the records in micro seconds. I wanted to know when it was written into the database in human readable format.
So please someone suggest me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Things like that are usually done in your client in your programming language of choice. The CQL shell is a bit restricted (by nature) for those operations.

There are a host of date-related functions in the CQL shell but they are supposed to be used in timeuuid values, not in the result of a query